Cannot connect to SQL Server Express with Windows Forms in Visual Studio 2022
I am receiving a connection error when connecting to SQL Server  2019 Express from a Windows Forms app in Visual Studio 2022 using C#. When I attempt to open the database I see this:

Cannot open database, the Login failed.

This is using Windows authentication with this connection string
Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=IMSBooks;Integrated Security = True

The database opens fine with SSMS using Windows authentication.  However, when I create a SQL Server login, it fails and I see this:

Error 233 no Process on the other end of the pipe.

I'm running Windows 11, SQL Server 2019 Express, and I verified the port is 1433 and also that Named Pipes are enabled. Security is set to "SQL Server and Windows authentication". SQL Server service and browser is running.
How can I resolve this?

fyi, Express Edition is still a server-class database that expects to run in the background and use lots of resources 24/7, even when your app is not active. This means it excels as a shared database for an app on many machines, or as the DB for a web site, but makes it a poor choice as a basic data store for a local Windows Forms app. If "local/single-user app" sounds like what you have, you should use an in-process database engine like sqlite or even Access instead.

You probably don't want Named Pipes. This answer might have useful information for you.

As you can connect to the instance using SSMS have you checked the SQL Errors to see why the logins are failing? Take note of the State numbers that appear in the Error 18456 messages and compare them against those shown at MSSQLSERVER_18456 # Additional error information to see exactly why the login was refused. If there are no Error 18456 messages at the same time then your app isn't even able to connect: did you restart the SQL Browser service?
